# Need help creating a script that can zip a folder and copy it to another place. (Linux/Ubuntu)

Tags: bash

I've looked everywhere, including this website for a script that can remove a .zip from a certain folder, zip a folder, and copy the new zip to the first folder, here's what I've managed to do:

```
 #!/bin/bash
    rm /var/www/html/files/MinecraftMods.zip
    zip -r MinecraftMods.zip ~/ForgeWorld/mods/
    mv ~/ForgeWorld/mods/MinecraftMods.zip /var/www/html/files/
```

This is the error message I'm getting:

```
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/www/html/files/MinecraftMods.zip’: No such file or directory
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/ (stored 0%)
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/QuiverBow_1.6.4_b49_Backport_4.zip (stored 0%)
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/ProjectRedCompat-1.6.4-4.3.7.32.jar (deflated 15%)
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/ProjectRedWorld-1.6.4-4.3.7.32.jar (deflated 10%)
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/OpenModsLib-0.5.jar (deflated 11%)
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/extrautils-1.0.3c.zip (stored 0%)
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/BiomesOPlenty-api-1.6.4-1.2.1.434.jar (deflated 14%)
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/CodeChickenCore 0.9.0.9.jar (deflated 8%)
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/ProjectRedIntegration-1.6.4-4.3.7.32.jar (deflated 10%)
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/Additional-Buildcraft-Objects-Mod-1.6.4.jar (deflated 14%)
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/CoFHCore-2.0.0.5.jar (deflated 19%)
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/OpenBlocks-1.2.8.jar (deflated 8%)
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/ProjectRedLighting-1.6.4-4.3.7.32.jar (deflated 10%)
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/buildcraft-A-1.6.4-4.2.2.jar (deflated 15%)
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/ProjectRedMechanical-BETA-1.6.4-4.3.7.32.jar (deflated 10%)
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/ic2/ (stored 0%)
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/ic2/ejml-0.23.jar (deflated 10%)
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/ChickenChunks 1.3.3.4.jar (deflated 9%)
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/1.6.4/ (stored 0%)
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/1.6.4/CodeChickenLib-universal-1.6.4-1.0.0.62.jar (deflated 11%)
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/1.6.4/ForgeMultipart-universal-1.6.4-1.0.0.244.jar (deflated 13%)
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/Industrial-Craft-2-Experimental-1.6.4.jar (deflated 9%)
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/ironchest-universal-1.6.4-5.4.1.677.zip (stored 0%)
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/NotEnoughItems 1.6.1.9.jar (deflated 6%)
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/ProjectRedBase-1.6.4-4.3.7.32.jar (deflated 24%)
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/LogisticsPipes-MC1.6.4-0.7.4.dev.217.jar (deflated 12%)
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/ThermalExpansion-3.0.0.7.jar (deflated 28%)
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/util^iChunUtil2.4.0.zip (stored 0%)
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/PortalGun2.0.2.zip (stored 0%)
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/EnderStorage 1.4.3.6.jar (deflated 11%)
updating: root/ForgeWorld/mods/appeng-rv14-finale3-mc16x.jar (deflated 13%)
mv: cannot stat ‘/root/ForgeWorld/mods/MinecraftMods.zip’: No such file or directory
```

My only problem is the last part, it finishes zipping the folder but the directory is not there, so I can't copy it to the /files/ folder. Help?

Comment: ***All*** of your tags were wrong.  This is exclusively a bash problem.

Comment: So ensure the directory exists first?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to put all of those folders under `/root`?  Seems like an unusual thing...running Minecraft as root...

Comment: @Makoto, sorry, I'm pretty new to the website so I just put in suggested tags.

Answer (score 1):

change: **`zip -r MinecraftMods.zip ~/ForgeWorld/mods/`**

to: **`zip -r ~/ForgeWorld/mods/MinecraftMods.zip ~/ForgeWorld/mods/`**

Answer (score 0):

The mv failed because the ZIP file was created in your current directory and NOT in ~/ForgeWorld/mods/.
By the way, I recommand you to NOT generate the ZIP file in this place because ZIP process is scanning this place. So your incomplete ZIP file will be in the final ZIP file... Probably not what you want.
By the way, use "-f" with rm to avoid the warning when the original do not exist. So I advice the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f /var/www/html/files/MinecraftMods.zip
zip -r /tmp/MinecraftMods.zip ~/ForgeWorld/mods/
mv /tmp/MinecraftMods.zip /var/www/html/files/
```